# What is thermal plasma in-flight oxidation technique?

Tags: terminology, photochemistry, plasma-chemistry

From Vijay, M.; Ramachandran, K.; Ananthapadmanabhan, P. V.; Nalini, B.; Pillai, B. C.; Bondioli, F.; Manivannan, A.; Narendhirakannan, R. T. *Current Applied Physics* **2013**, 13 (3), 510–516. DOI [10.1016/j.cap.2012.09.014](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cap.2012.09.014):

> Since large quantity of energy is consumed to vaporize the solvent in liquid precursors, a novel method that involves thermal plasma **in-flight** oxidation of $\ce{TiH2}$ has been developed to synthesize nanocrystalline $\ce{TiO2}$."

What does in-flight mean in this context? Obviously it doesn't have anything to do with actual flying, but everywhere I look it says that it is used for something that occurrs or is provided during an aircraft flight.

The article is about photocatalytic inactivation of bacteria by reactive plasma nanocrystalline $\ce{TiO2}$ powder. It suggests a new method for the physical preparation of $\ce{TiO2}$ for a novel reactor.

Comment: @andselisk Thanks! Elsevier's DOI linking hub is down for me at the moment, but the citation was enough for me to find it. http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1567173912003926

Answer (score 7):

Original paper where this method (and, I guess, the term itself) has been introduced was written in Japanese in 1982 [1]. In 1997 there was a great overview published in English by Toyonobu Yoshida, author of the original paper, with a chapter (2.3) devoted to this particular method:

> Processes used to manufacture materials by injecting a solid, liquid, or gas into a thermal plasma to use its high enthalpy and reactivity are referred to as **in-flight** plasma processes (IFP processes).

Due to the nature of the method which utilizes plasma jet with reactants generated via various torch-types, there is actually **a flow** of chemicals reacting while they "**fly**", of course, in the plasma area.

[image]

Various plasma torches provide various times-of-flight, temperatures and velocities. For example, the direct current jet torch has the following characteristics:

> An argon plasma of about $\pu{80 kW}$ that has been generated in air reportedly produces a temperature of about $\pu{11600 K}$ and a velocity of about $\pu{410 m/s}$... The reaction time for reactants injected near the anode at high temperatures is about $\pu{400 \mu s}$ and the gaseous raw materials are 
>   mainly used for the synthesis of fine powders... The reaction time of the reactants is estimated to be $\pu{1 ms}$.

#### Bibliography

1. Yoshida, T.; Akashi, K. *Tetsu-to-Hagane* **1982**, 68 (10), 1498–1502. DOI [10.2355/tetsutohagane1955.68.10_1498](https://doi.org/10.2355/tetsutohagane1955.68.10_1498).
2. *Ultra-fine particles: exploratory science and technology*; Hayashi, C., Uyeda, R., Tasaki, A., Eds.; Materials science and process technology series; Noyes Publications: Westwood, N.J, **1997**. ISBN 978-0-8155-1404-6.

Answer (score 2):

Further down in the paper, the following image and accompanying text are present:

> [image]
>
> Fig. 1. Schematic of plasma reactor (1 – Plasma torch, 2 – Reactor, 3 – Filter and 4 – Exhaust).
>
> As the powder particles enter the plasma jet, they get heated up and
>   $\ce{TiH2}$ dissociates into $\ce{Ti}$ particles and hydrogen gas. Both $\ce{Ti}$ particles
>   and hydrogen gas react with oxygen to form $\ce{TiO2}$ and water vapor
>   respectively; the latter escapes along with the exhaust gas stream. In
>   addition to the particle heating by the plasma, the energy released by
>   the exothermic reaction between Ti particles and oxygen helps to
>   dissociate the formed $\ce{TiO2}$ particles into Ti vapor and oxygen gas. The
>   Ti vapor reacts with oxygen at the tail of the plasma jet forming
>   nanoclusters of $\ce{TiO2}$ particles.

So what happens is that a stream of $\ce{TiH2}$ particles are sent into the reactor on a stream of gas (in other words, flying into the reactor). The oxidation occurs while the particles are *in-flight*, not before they hit the plasma or after they're collected, presumably on the filter.

So *in-flight* here means the same thing it does in other contexts, but the flight is the flight of $\ce{TiH2}$ particles on a stream of gas/plasma.